# Sampling $X$ having $F_X(x) = \prod_{i=1}^nF_{X_i}(x)$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, sampling, simulation

How can I use relation $F_X(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n F_{X_i}(x)$ to sample $X$ knowing it is easy to generate random variable form any distribution $F_{X_i} , i = 1 , \ldots , n$? Suppose $X_i$'s are independent random variables.

Comment: Multiplying density functions $f_i(x_i)$ of independent marginals give the likelihood of the sample $x_i, x_2, \dots, x_n.$ Multiplying the CDFs $F_i(x_i)$ of indep observations gives the CDF of their minimum. I don't see how either of these multiplications is directly relevant to using quantile function (inverse CDF) to simulate data from a particular dist'n.

Comment: @BruceET what do you mean by "Multiplying the $CDF$s $F_i(x_i)$ of indep observations gives the $CDF$ of their minimum" ? i don't get it. I don't know about relevance to inverse but maybe we should be looking for a relation between $X_i$'s and $X$.i mean what random variable $X$ has distribution function $F_X$ .probably finally we we should sample $X_i$'s and then do some operation on them to get a sample of $X$.

Comment: Sorry, should have said 'max', not 'min': Let $W=\max(X_1,X_2),$ with $X_i$ iid CDF $F_X.$ Then $F_W(w) = P(W\le w) = P(X_i\le w,X_2\le w)$ $=(F_X(w))^2.$  For $V = \min(X_1,X_2),$ define reliability fcn as $R_V(v) = 1 - F_V(v).$ Then $R_V(v) = (R_X(v))^2.$

Comment: @BruceET I was wondering if you want to write a complete (extensive) answer and and i accept it as correct answer . I wanted to sample $F_X(x) = x^n$ so i used what you mentioned and generated $n$ uniform(0,1) and picked the max of this n values as my sample.